# Blazor WebAssembly using GRPC

Tags: grpc, autofac, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web

I have a Blazor WebAssembly web application and want to use an existing GRPC service.

When I open a new channel, I get the following error message:

```
Channel = new Channel(_settings.RemoteAddress, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
 
'Unsupported architecture "Unknown".'
```

GRPC service is initialized with Autofac.

Following packages are installed.

```
Grpc.Net.Client (2.40.0)
Grpc.Net.Client.Web (2.40.0)
```

Does anyone have an idea whether this is possible with Blazor WebAssembly or what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must still have a reference to the older Grpc.Core package.  To use Grpc.Net.Client your code should look something like this:

```
var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWebText, new HttpClientHandler());
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(_settings.RemoteAddress, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
```